# FriendlyPix iOS - user does not have permission storage error

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I just installed FriendlyPix iOS and followed all the steps listed on the readme including deploying the cloud functions and rules. I am getting an error and I think it has to do with the storage rules. The error I get is:

User does not have permission to access gs://friendlypixsk.appspot.com/HS4uNP1BYNNnW2Qf59azZH8i3gp2/full/-LAoHLCCMnlD8RoFhUNd/jpeg.

This happens in the uploadPressed function in FPUploadViewController. It happens in the fullref.downloadURL function call. The closure passed to that function is getting an error.

The Firebase Storage rules I have are as follows:

```
// Returns true if the given UID matches the signed in UID,
// the uploaded file is an image and its size is below the given number of MB.
// Also allow deletes.
function isImageAndBelowMaxSize(uid, maxSizeMB) {
  return request.auth.token.admin == true || (request.auth.uid == uid
      && (request.resource == null // Allow deletes
          || request.resource.size < maxSizeMB * 1024 * 1024 // Max size for the uploaded file
              && request.resource.contentType.matches('image/.*'))) // The file is an image
}

service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{userId}/thumb/{postId}/{fileName} {
      allow read, write: if isImageAndBelowMaxSize(userId, 1);
    }
    match /{userId}/full/{postId}/{fileName} {
      allow read, write: if isImageAndBelowMaxSize(userId, 5);
    }
  }
}
```

I have not modified them at all. The image does get uploaded and I can see it in the firebase console. I'm a little new to firebase and not sure exactly how these rules work. I have signed in using google sign in.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem, also permissions on the downloadUR call, although the image is uploaded - any resolutions?